# How to design a schema of many-to-many relation that one of the tables is to store ordered items?

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

The ordered items are trip itineraries, which have attributes `origin_city_id`, `destination_city_id`, `departure_date`.

There is another table `pax` that has attributes like `adult`, `children`.

A pax-itineraries pair forms a trip. So there should be a many-to-many relation relating pax to itineraries.
Some case might be like:

Trip_1 = [ 'pax' => Pax_1, 'itineraries' => [Itinerary_1, Itinerary_2]]

Trip_2 = [ 'pax' => Pax_1, 'itineraries' => [Itinerary_1, Itinerary_2, Itinerary_3]]

Trip_3 = [ 'pax' => Pax_2, 'itineraries' => [Itinerary_1, Itinerary_2]]

If the query is [ 'pax' => Pax_1, 'itineraries' => [Itinerary_1, Itinerary_2]], only Trip_1 should be returned.

At first I use a many-to-many relation to relate tables `trips` to `itineraries`, but later found it hard to build the relation since I will have lots of record for a trip. Also the search might be difficult to implement since I need to find the itinerary set that only includes Itinerary_1 and Itinerary_2.

What I tried now is to revise the table `itineraries` into a self reference table with a foreign key `next_itinerary_id` to indicate the next itinerary, and column `first` to indicate if the itinerary is the first itinerary. After that building the many-to-many relation is much easier that I only need to relate `pax_id` with `first_itinerary_id`.

But when finding out the set of the itineraries of the query, I need to query every  itinerary, which I am not sure if I am doing it right.

Is any step that I did is wrong?
Is there any better implementation?
Or is there any reference that I can study?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google `database design tutorial`

Comment: You have your table with fields like src , dest, date, other stats. This is only table you have that I can tell from your question. What relations and order do you talk about?

Comment: I think I oversimplify my problems, but still thanks a lots. I am looking for some tutorials to better understand and describe my question.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see what you have tried.  If you had posted your models and the relationships, it would be easier to see.  You should reference [Laravel's many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for reference if you are having trouble

Then, you can eager load the `itineraries` table on each of your pax.  This gives you access to all itineraries for each pax, and is searchable as you have requested.